# GWT 2.4 DataGrid - Header not aligned with Data, When Horizontal Scroll Bar shows up

Tags: gwt

The table header is not aligned with the data when the horizontal bar shows up.

If there's no scrolling then the header is aligned correctly.

Tested with GWT2.4 on

IE8 Windows7 and IE7 WinXP

With Chrome it works.

Is there a work around?
Am I doing something wrong?

```
public void onModuleLoad()
{
    DataGrid table = createTable();
    RootLayoutPanel rp = RootLayoutPanel.get();
    rp.add(table);

}


DataGrid createTable()
{
    ArrayList<HashMap> list = new ArrayList<HashMap>();

    HashMap row = new HashMap();
    row.put("1", true);
    row.put("2", "Model ABC");
    row.put("3", "1X1.5-6");
    row.put("4", "0.344");
    row.put("5", "IRON");
    row.put("6", "3,500");
    row.put("7", "102");
    row.put("8", "4.458");
    row.put("9", "57.5");
    row.put("10", "31.403");
    row.put("11", "5.5");

    list.add(row);

    DataGrid table = new DataGrid();

    Column columnDef2 = new Column<HashMap, Boolean>(new CheckboxCell())
    {
        @Override
        public Boolean getValue(HashMap object)
        {
            return (Boolean) object.get("1");
        }
    };
    table.addColumn(columnDef2, "1");
    table.setColumnWidth(columnDef2, 100, Unit.PX);

    Column columnDef = new Column<HashMap, String>(new TextCell())
    {
        @Override
        public String getValue(HashMap object)
        {
            return (String) object.get("2");
        }
    };
    table.addColumn(columnDef, "2");
    table.setColumnWidth(columnDef, 100, Unit.PX);

    columnDef = new Column<HashMap, String>(new TextCell())
    {
        @Override
        public String getValue(HashMap object)
        {
            return (String) object.get("3");
        }
    };
    table.addColumn(columnDef, "3");
    table.setColumnWidth(columnDef, 100, Unit.PX);

    columnDef = new Column<HashMap, String>(new TextCell())
    {
        @Override
        public String getValue(HashMap object)
        {
            return (String) object.get("4");
        }
    };
    table.addColumn(columnDef, "4");
    table.setColumnWidth(columnDef, 100, Unit.PX);

    columnDef = new Column<HashMap, String>(new TextCell())
    {
        @Override
        public String getValue(HashMap object)
        {
            return (String) object.get("5");
        }
    };
    table.addColumn(columnDef, "5");
    table.setColumnWidth(columnDef, 100, Unit.PX);

    columnDef = new Column<HashMap, String>(new TextCell())
    {
        @Override
        public String getValue(HashMap object)
        {
            return (String) object.get("6");
        }
    };
    table.addColumn(columnDef, "6");
    table.setColumnWidth(columnDef, 100, Unit.PX);

    columnDef = new Column<HashMap, String>(new TextCell())
    {
        @Override
        public String getValue(HashMap object)
        {
            return (String) object.get("7");
        }
    };
    table.addColumn(columnDef, "7");
    table.setColumnWidth(columnDef, 100, Unit.PX);

    columnDef = new Column<HashMap, String>(new TextCell())
    {
        @Override
        public String getValue(HashMap object)
        {
            return (String) object.get("8");
        }
    };
    table.addColumn(columnDef, "8");
    table.setColumnWidth(columnDef, 100, Unit.PX);

    columnDef = new Column<HashMap, String>(new TextCell())
    {
        @Override
        public String getValue(HashMap object)
        {
            return (String) object.get("9");
        }
    };
    table.addColumn(columnDef, "9");
    table.setColumnWidth(columnDef, 100, Unit.PX);

    columnDef = new Column<HashMap, String>(new TextCell())
    {
        @Override
        public String getValue(HashMap object)
        {
            return (String) object.get("10");
        }
    };
    table.addColumn(columnDef, "10");
    table.setColumnWidth(columnDef, 100, Unit.PX);

    columnDef = new Column<HashMap, String>(new TextCell())
    {
        @Override
        public String getValue(HashMap object)
        {
            return (String) object.get("11");
        }
    };
    table.addColumn(columnDef, "11");
    table.setColumnWidth(columnDef, 100, Unit.PX);

    table.setRowCount(list.size(), true);
    table.setRowData(0, list);

    return table;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well it turns out that for IE8 the compatibilty button was pressed, while IE7 runs by default on compatibility mode.